# What does this rm -r command do in following usecase on mac terminal?

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, bash, terminal

First I'm directing to the destination folder by below command

```
cd /Users/myname/MyFolder/
```

Now I'm using below command here, what does this command will do?

```
rm -r ../build ../dist
```

`rm` command is for removing, but I'm not able to know how will it work on `build` and `dist` directory, and also what does `..` mean here?

Answer (score 0):

The command will (attempt to) remove directories `/Users/myname/build` and `/Users/myname/dist` along with all of their contents.

(`..` refers to the parent directory)

Comment: `/MyFolder` has no use here? And I'm getting `no such directory found` on running above command. What can be the possible reasons?

Comment: Correct.  The `..` means "move up one directory", so the commands are not working inside `MyFolder`.  The message `no such directory found` simply indicates that `/Users/myname/build` and/or `/Users/myname/dist` do not exist to begin with, so there is nothing to remove.

Comment: Is there any way to automate the remove operation, like if the directory is present then remove it, else do nothing? Thanks for the above clarification.

Comment: Yes you can add the `-f` force flag to `rm`.  Given this flag, if `rm` can't find the directory, it will silently ignore it.

Comment: Warning: `rm` deletes files and directories without a way to recover them. If you don't understand what it's going to do, then there's a significant chance you'll delete something you didn't mean to. Automating it just increases this risk. You need to start by being clear about what you want to accomplish, and then make sure the commands you use do that, *and only that*. BTW, how good are your backups?